# Where my file goes with gcloud compute scp command?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, scp

I am trying to move my local file to my newly created gcp vm instance named 'instance-1'. I tried this command:

```sh
gcloud compute scp D:\FPX\new_tst.txt instance-1:
```

It tells me:

```sh
new_tst.txt               | 0 kB |   0.2 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

This means there is no error. But when I check on vm instance using cloud shell in the browser, I don't see any file.

I have checked root folder `/`, `/home/$USER`, `/tmp` but couldn't find any where.

Can someone guide me where it goes?

Comment: Try specifying a path after instance-1, like `~/`.

Comment: @Shahnaz To find the file, you can always use this command '$find / -name filename'

Answer (score 0):

### Finding file

If you just want to find out where your file goes after `gcloud compute scp` command, then you can try to find out the file by following @Fady’s suggestion. I would suggest first changing to the **root user** by using `sudo -s` command once you have sshed into the VM from cloud shell, then run the below command which will search the whole `/` directory tree.

> [root@instance-1]# find / -name new_tst.txt

*Note: I believe you are using a Linux VM and your local machine is windows.*

### Moving a file from local to GCP VM

You can use the below command to do the [SCP from local windows machine](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) to the GCP VM. You need to specify the path of destination VM and make sure the user has the write access to it and also the directory *already exists* in the destination VM. This example command uses users home directory.

> gcloud compute scp C:\test\file.txt user@instance-1:/home/user --zone zonename

However, before doing so you need to authenticate properly with `gcloud auth login` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) and use the authorized service account or user to do the task. It is a good idea to check with `gcloud auth list` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list) to list credentialed accounts. Whichever account has an asterisk beside it, is the active account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried following three things - 1) `>gcloud compute scp D:\FPX\new_tst.txt <username>@instance-1:/sampleDir` . This gives me 'permission denied'  2) `gcloud compute scp D:\FPX\new_tst.txt <username>@instance-1:~/sampleDir. This gives me `unable to open ~/sampleDir: no such file or directory`  3) if I fire `gcloud compute scp D:\FPX\new_tst.txt <username>@instance-1:sampleDir', I get the message `new_tst.txt               | 0 kB |   0.2 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%`. But when I try to find same file on my instance, I get nothing. I don't know what else I am missing?

Comment: @ShahnazKhan I believe your user `<username>` does not have permission to write to `sampleDir`. Try using the user’s home directory instead (ex. username is `foo`) => `gcloud compute scp D:\FPX\new_tst.txt foo@instance-1:/home/foo` or make sure user foo has the write access to `sampleDir` which is under `/` directory in your example. 

I am going forward and editing the answer for better understanding.